# 得られたデータ(deque)を書式に合わせてcsvに出力したいです．

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

現在，筋電センサを用いて動作推定するプログラムを作っているのですが，個人学習する際に得られるデータをトーレーニングデータの書式（csv)と同じようにcsvに出力したいと考えています．使用している筋電センサは8電極あり，8行1列の行列値でデータが取得できます．

例　deque([160067619223897, [-12, 13, 2, 4, 1, 4, 0, 0])のような形式で表示されます．

一方で，トレーニングデータはcsvファイルの1つのセルに1；2；3；4；（省略）63；64；のように64行1列で；で区切られている書式になっています．つまり，８要素のdequeを８個繋げてかつ；で各数字を区切る必要があります．データは貯めておいて連結して8個毎に区切って出力し、次の8個を連結して出力できるようにしたいです。前回，ご回答いただいたコードで実行したところ，8個のデータを連結して，出力できました．ありがとうございます．**しかし，最初の64個分のデータは出力されたのですが，さらに次の64個のデータも出力したいです．つまり，8要素のデータを8個繋げて64要素のデータの出力を繰り返し行いたいです．大変，恐縮ですが，ご教示頂けないでしょうか？**

どなたか，このようなcsvへの出力の仕方をご存知の方おりませんでしょうか？おりましたら，ぜひご教示ください．以下にデータを取得するコードを記載いたします．gesture列に関しては付与です。
また，下記のコードを実装すると毎回8個ずつデータがプリントされます．1つめの大きなデータはデータの番号ですdeque([], maxlen=8)
以下に実行された時のテキストエディタは以下のようになります．（一部記載）

```
deque([], maxlen=8) paired XDirection.toward_elbow deque([], maxlen=8)
deque([(1601359906744595, [2, 3, 2, -13, -3, 5, 1, 11]), (1601359906744595, 
[-2, -5, -7, 2, -9, -2, 0, 2])], maxlen=8) deque([(1601359906800668, [-2, -4, 
-3, -9, 7, -10, -2, -24]), (1601359906800668, [-1, -1, 1, -27, -108, -18, -4, 
-8]), (1601359906824581, [1, 3, 4, 25, 35, 14, 2, -2]), (1601359906824581, 
[-2, -1, -9, -31, -95, -27, -6, 3]), (1601359906826582, [3, 3, 16, 55, 83, 
31, 6, 9]), (1601359906826582, [-8, 0, -7, -26, -20, -11, -4, -40]), 
(1601359906838606, [-1, -4, -10, -42, -97, -29, -8, -12]), (1601359906838606, 
[5, 5, 12, 61, 126, 25, 9, 29])], maxlen=8)
deque([(1601359906919984, [-2, -6, -8, 43, 8, -1, -3, -6]),(1601359906919984, 
 [0, -2, 1, -1, 3, -2, -3, 1]), (1601359906936890, [-1, -1, 4, -23, -27, -2, 
 1, 0]), (1601359906936890, [-3, -8, -10, -12, 6, -1, -1, -4]), 
 (1601359906951941, [1, 4, 4, 24, 3, 1, -2, -5]
```

また，使用しているトレーニングデータは以下のリンクのものを参考にしています．dataディレクトリの中のtrain_data_set.csvです．この形式で出力したいです．
https://github.com/exelban/myo-armband-nn

```
from collections import deque
from threading import Lock
import myo
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
class MyListener(myo.DeviceListener):
"""
classe en écoute d'un myo
"""
def __init__(self, queue_size=8):
    self.lock = Lock()  # verrouille le thread pour lecture des donnees
    # création de listes optimisées pour seulement ajouter des éléments
    self.emg_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
    self.orientation_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
    self.acceleration_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
    self.gyroscope_data_queue = deque(maxlen=queue_size)
    self.rssi_data_queue = deque(maxlen=100)
    # initialisation d'attribut
    self.pose = myo.Pose.rest  # pose quelconque
    self.connected = False  # non connecté
    self.battery_level = 100  # niveau de batterie maximal
    self.emg_enabled = False  # on acquiert pas les EMG
    self.locked = False  # myo non vérouillé
    self.rssi = None  # aucune valeur de force du signal bluetooth
    self.emg = None  # données null des emg
    self.device_name = None  # pas de nom du myo
    self.device = None
    self.myo_firmware = None
    self.arm = None
    self.x_direction = None
    self.sync = None

def on_paired(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le myo est appareillé
    """
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('paired')
    else:
        pass

def on_unpaired(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le myo n'est plus appareillé
    """
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('unpaired')
    else:
        pass

def on_connected(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelé si le myo est connecté
    """
    self.device = event.device  # sauvegarde de l'instance au myo arm
    event.device.unlock()  # demande de desappareiller
    event.device.lock()  # demande d'appareiller (génère des vibrations)
    event.device.stream_emg(True)  # lance l'acquisition des emg
    self.connected = True  # mise à jour du flag de connection du myo
    self.device_name = event.device_name  # on récupère le petit nom du myo
    # on récupère également le numéro du firmware (non exploité dans l'UI)
    self.myo_firmware = '.'.join(map(str, event.firmware_version[:-1]))

def on_disconnected(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le myo est déconnecté
    """
    self.connected = False  # flag mis à jour

def on_arm_synced(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelé si un bras est synchronisé
    pas vraiment compris !!!
    """
    self.sync = True
    self.arm = event.arm  # informe de la latéralité du bras détecté
    # informe de l'orientation du bracelet
    # (vers le poignet ou vers le coude)
    self.x_direction = event.x_direction
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(self.x_direction)
    else:
        pass

def on_arm_unsynced(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le bras est désynchronisé
    pas vraiment compris !!!
    """
    self.sync = False
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(f'arm unsynced : {event.arm}')
    else:
        pass

def on_unlocked(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le myo est dévérouillé
    """
    self.locked = False  # flag mis à jour

def on_locked(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée si le myo est vérouillé
    """
    self.locked = True  # flag mis à jour

def on_pose(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée dès qu'une pose gestuelle est reconnue

        a) Spread
        b) Fist
        c) Wave in
        d) Wave out
        e) Double Tap
        f) Rest
    """
    self.pose = event.pose  # attribut mis à jour

def on_orientation(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée pour récupérer

        a) orientation
        b) gyroscope
        c) accéléromètre
        d) associé à un timestamp
    """
    with self.lock:
        self.orientation_data_queue.append((event.timestamp,
                                            event.orientation))
        self.gyroscope_data_queue.append((event.timestamp,
                                          event.gyroscope))
        self.acceleration_data_queue.append((event.timestamp,
                                             event.acceleration))

def on_rssi(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée suite à la réponse d'une requête "request_rssi()"
    """
    with self.lock:
        # mise à jour de la liste
        self.rssi_data_queue.append(-event.rssi)

def on_battery_level(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée dès que le niveau de batterie évolue
    """
    self.battery_level = event.battery_level  # mise à jour de l'attribut

def on_emg(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée pour réceptionner les données EMG
    avec son timestamp
    """
    with self.lock:
        self.emg_data_queue.append((event.timestamp,
                                    event.emg))

def on_warmup_completed(self, event):
    """
    méthode appelée quand le myo arm est "chaud"

    c'est à partir de ce moment que les données sont les plus stables
    mais ça reste à vérifier

    pas vraiment pris en compte dans ce code (à faire évoluer)
    """
    event.device.stream_emg(True)  # lancement de l'acquisition EMG
    self.emg_enabled = True  # mise à jour du flag

def get_emg_data(self):
    """
    méthode pour récupérer les données EMGs
    """
    with self.lock:
        return list(self.emg_data_queue)

def get_orientation_data(self):
    """
    méthode pour récupérer les données d'orientation
    """
    with self.lock:
        return list(self.orientation_data_queue)

def get_gyroscope_data(self):
    """
    méthode pour récupérer les données du gyroscope
    """
    with self.lock:
        return list(self.gyroscope_data_queue)

def get_accelerometor_data(self):
    """
    méthode pour récupérer les données de l'accéléromètre
    """
    with self.lock:
        return list(self.acceleration_data_queue)


if __name__ == '__main__':
# permet de tester sans interface graphique
#import os
from time import sleep
myo.init(bin_path=r'C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\myo-sdk-win-0.9.0\bin')
HUB = myo.Hub()
LISTENER = MyListener()
with HUB.run_in_background(LISTENER.on_event):
    while True:
        print(LISTENER.emg_data_queue)
        np.savetxt("data.csv", LISTENER.emg_data_queue, fmt="%r", delimiter=",")
```

sleep(0.1)deque([], maxlen=8)

**また，ご教示頂いたコードで実装してみました．

以下に変更した部分を記載いたします．**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
from time import sleep
myo.init(bin_path=r'C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\myo-sdk-win-0.9.0\bin')
HUB = myo.Hub()
LISTENER = MyListener()
emg64 = []
with HUB.run_in_background(LISTENER.on_event):
    while True:
        print(LISTENER.emg_data_queue)
        emg64 = [';'.join(map(str, sum([e[1] for e in 
                 LISTENER.emg_data_queue], []))) + ';']
        np.savetxt("data.csv", emg64, fmt= "%s", delimiter=",")

        sleep(0.1)
```

以前，教えて頂きまして，以下のコードのように変更しました．8個貯まる要素を8個連結する作業を繰り返し行いたいです．エクセルに連続して，64個のデータを主力していきたいです．上記で示しましたtrain_data_set.csvのように．ご教示の程，よろしくお願い申し上げます．

Comment: 例として挙げられている deque はこれで正しいですか……？　括弧の対応が合っていないのと、ひとつ目の大きな数が何なのかがよく分かりませんでした。

Comment: 質問の更新部分が太字で強調されて分かりやすくなりましたが、その元となったのは私が 9月30日 14:13 に改訂する前の古いコーディングでの状況のようです。新しい処理を試してみてください。それでどのような結果になるか、まだ問題が残っているならどういう状況かを分離して追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

質問記事の加筆修正に対応して改訂：

`LISTENER.emg_data_queue`が0～8個の`deque`データであり、それをバッファリングして8個貯まる毎に1つのデータとして連結して出力するには、以下のようにして出来るはずです。

```
with HUB.run_in_background(LISTENER.on_event):
    emg_buffer = []
    while True:
        print(LISTENER.emg_data_queue)
        if LISTENER.emg_data_queue:
            emg_buffer.extend([e[1] for e in LISTENER.emg_data_queue])
            LISTENER.emg_data_queue.clear()
        
        if len(emg_buffer) >= 8:
            emg64 = [';'.join(map(str, sum(emg_buffer[:8], []))) + ';']
            np.savetxt("data.csv", emg64, fmt="%s", delimiter=",")
            emg_buffer = emg_buffer[8:] if len(emg_buffer) > 8 else []
        
        sleep(0.1)
```